# How to make every two rows in a SwiftUI Grid tappable using NavigationLink without changing its layout?

Tags: swift, swiftui, layout, grid, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a SwiftUI code snippet that displays a Grid with multiple rows and columns. Each row consists of several elements, with the elements in the first column aligning to the leading edge, while the elements in the remaining columns aligns to the trailing edge. I would like to introduce a NavigationLink to make every two rows tappable as a single button w/o changing the grid layout. For example, when a user taps on any element in the first two rows(Row1A - Row1111A AND Row1B - Row1111B ), it should navigate to a specific view.

Here's my code snippet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            Grid(alignment: .trailing, horizontalSpacing: 20) {
                GridRow {
                    ForEach(1..<5) { column in
                        Text("Column \(column)")
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                ForEach(1..<7) { row in
                    GridRow {
                        Text("Row \(row) A")
                            .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)
                        Text("Row \(row)\(row) A")
                        Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row) A")
                        Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row)\(row) A")
                    }
                    GridRow {
                        Text("Row \(row) B")
                        Text("Row \(row)\(row) B")
                        Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row) B")
                        Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row)\(row) B")
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

```
ForEach(1..<7) { row in
    NavigationLink {
        Text("View \(row)")
    } label: {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("Row \(row) A")
                    .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)
                Text("Row \(row)\(row) A")
                Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row) A")
                Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row)\(row) A")
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Row \(row) B")
                Text("Row \(row)\(row) B")
                Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row) B")
                Text("Row \(row)\(row)\(row)\(row) B")
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

I used a "Grid" container to combine two GridRows into a single label, but since I introduced a new Grid for every two rows,  I am unable to align the elements in the first column to the leading edge while aligning the elements in the remaining columns to the trailing edge. I also tried "Group" and "VStack", but it did not provide the desired layout for aligning the elements as intended. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using LazyVStack instead.